# How does the simplied commonJS wrapper work in require.js under the hood?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, commonjs

Consider this example from their website

```
define(function (require) {
    var foo = require('foo');

    //Define this module as exporting a function
    return function () {
        foo.doSomething();
    };
});
```

My question is, as 'foo' is loaded asynchronously, how does the Javascript below it not execute before it has loaded?

Comment: Where did you find that example? Dependencies have to be passed as first argument to `define`. http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#define

Comment: @FelixKling http://requirejs.org/docs/commonjs.html  under 'Setting Exported Value'

Comment: Ah OK. This is explained here: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#cjsmodule and http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#sugar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is explained in http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#cjsmodule and http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#sugar.

Require.js will at some point (before running the function) look at the *string representation* of the function, find all `require` calls to determine the dependencies and load them.

> To make this easier, and to make it easy to do a simple wrapping around CommonJS modules, this form of define is supported, sometimes referred to as "simplified CommonJS wrapping":
>
> ```
> define(function (require) {
>     var dependency1 = require('dependency1'),
>         dependency2 = require('dependency2'); 
>     return function () {};
> });
> ```
>
> The AMD loader will parse out the `require('')` calls by using `Function.prototype.toString()`, then internally convert the above define call into this:
>
> ```
> define(['require', 'dependency1', 'dependency2'], function (require) {
>     var dependency1 = require('dependency1'),
>         dependency2 = require('dependency2');
>     return function () {};
> });
> ```
>
> This allows the loader to load `dependency1` and `dependency2` asynchronously, execute those dependencies, then execute this function.